# Why does this query work inside a block but not inside custom Panel content?

Tags: mysql, drupal-6, drupal-panels

Why does the following query work within a Drupal Block, but not when part of a "custom content" in a pane within a Panels Page? It gives an error saying to check the syntax of the query near "AND node.type in....". Also, if I put it in a Block then display that Block inside a Panels Page, it works just fine. So while I've got this working... I really want to know why it wouldn't work when placed directly in the Panel content.

```
<?php
global $user;
if($user->uid) {
$result = db_query("Select COUNT(node.nid) from {node}
   LEFT JOIN {flag_content} flag_content_node 
       ON node.nid = flag_content_node.content_id AND 
       flag_content_node.fid = 7 
       where node.uid = %d AND node.type in ('node_type') AND
       (flag_content_node.uid IS NULL)", $user->uid);

$item_count = db_result($result);

print $item_count;
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably something wrong with your parameter to the query, because it's there that it goes wrong. Perhaps if `$user->uid` is null? Would it then insert '' into the query instead of the "%d"? That would seem odd.

It would also imply that you're not logged in.

No, that can't be, as you check that `$user->uid` is true, first.

Comment: I don't think it's the argument... i'm getting it from the global  $user so it shouldn't matter right? Also, plenty more questions like this to help with over on http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Still, there's something wrong with the resulting SQL. You should print out (or log) the SQL and the parameter value, as that is the only clue.

Comment: BTW Did you say `global $user`? Because if you didn't, depending on the file was originally loaded, the scope for a variable can change: you may see may or may not see the global variable.